# Programmatically Implement Guide Access in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, guided-access

I know how to implement guided access mode manually from the settings app. I have a requirement to lock ios device to one app. So for example parent can lock his child to one app in iphone device so he can not use any other apps in his device.

I have to implement this functionality programmatically? Do any one know how to install configuration profile and mdm profile programmatically so after doing this we will only have to write just one line of code

```
UIAccessibilityRequestGuidedAccessSession(true) { success in
    print("Request guided access success \(success)")
}
```

to enable guided access mode. Any one have any idea to implement that type of functionality please tell me? Thanks

Comment: You can't install an MDM profile "programatically". The user needs to install a management profile from a web site. You need MDM software (either purchase or write) to create the profile.

Answer (score 0):

I explored this problem earlier and found that guided access can not be achieved via programming rather we can set **Kiosk Mode** of an iOS device.

In kiosk mode, iOS device will have only 1 app, and this app will be the default interface of the iOS device. No any other apps can be installed, It will be like **Supervised Mode Enabled** device.

For more details:

[Why-Kiosk-Mode-is-Better?](https://www.webascender.com/blog/setup-kiosk-mode-lock-ipad-just-one-app-part-2/)

[Some-More-Details](https://blog.mobilock.in/how-to-lock-your-iphone-or-ipad-into-kiosk-mode/)

Comment: but this is using the same thing MDM profile using MobileLock software how can we implement that product our selves please answer on it.

Comment: It is not necessary @AdilAnwer, In 1st link I just shared, it is explained how you can set  kiosk mode for your iOS device. MDM profile needed if you wish to get more configuration.